# Reset Password and send email

Tags: asp.net, passwords, reset

Can you tell me what is wrong with the following code?
It changes password with the new one, saves it successfully to the DB, sends an email to the user BUT when I try to login with the new password, I receive an error:

> Invalid username or password

```
protected void SendEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = string.Empty;
        string password = string.Empty;
        string newPassword = "temp_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        var manager = new UserManager();
        string newPasswordHash = manager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword("newPassword");
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username, [PasswordHash] FROM AspNetUsers WHERE Email = @Email"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        username = sdr["Username"].ToString();
                        password = sdr["PasswordHash"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AspNetUsers set PasswordHash=@Password WHERE Email=@Email"))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", newPasswordHash);


            }

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("****@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
            mm.Body = string.Format("Your temporary password is {0}<br /><br /> You are advised to login and change it immediately.<br /><br />Thank You.", newPassword);
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "*****@gmail.com";
            NetworkCred.Password = "*****";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblMessage.Text = "A temporary password has been sent to your email address.";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "This email address does not match our records.";
        }
}
```

login.aspx.cs
public partial class Account_Login : Page
{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register";
            //OpenAuthLogin.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
            var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
            }
        }

```
    protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user password
            var manager = new UserManager();
            ApplicationUser user = manager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: where you are executing the **update command**?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are not updating your password.Below line will not update your password.it will just add parameter to parameter collection.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AspNetUsers set PasswordHash=@Password WHERE Email=@Email"))
            {
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", newPasswordHash);
            }
```

use the below code

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AspNetUsers set PasswordHash=@Password WHERE Email=@Email"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", newPasswordHash);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    int row=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if(row==1)
                      {
                        //success
                      }
                    else
                     {
                       //failed
                     }
                }
            }
```

Comment: check the table if password is getting updated or not

Comment: then something must be wrong with your login approach.if you add that code we can check what is happening.

Comment: I added my login.aspx.cs to my question. Please tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: problem must be in **manager.find** method.you are telling that the password id upadated.so the problem must  be in the method you are fetching the values.try to debug and check each and every value

Answer (score 0):

The "`PasswordHash`" Data Type is "`nvarchar`" in my `AspNetUsers` table, but you are defining and assigning "`Password`" as "`String`". `Nvarchar` stores UNICODE data where as String stores ASCII data. That may be contributing to the failure.